# KeyError When Selecting a Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to call a field and getting an error.

Calling any field in this table gets the same error.

```
df_ret = pd.read_csv('Retention Data.csv', na_values=['.'])
print(df_ret["Cohorts Retention Rate"])
```

This is what my data looks like:

[image]

This is the error I get:

> KeyError: 'Cohorts Retention Rate'

Using:

```
2.7.13 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep 21 2017, 17:38:20) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
```

Comment: What happens if you try `df_ret.columns = df_ret.columns.str.strip()` before querying a field?

Comment: That worked! Much Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be whitespace in your column names. You can remove whitespace as follows:

```
df_ret.columns = df_ret.columns.str.strip()
```

You can then access the series as expected:

```
print(df_ret['Cohorts Retention Rate'])
```

Comment: Simple and useful. After two days, this solved my issue with a massive dataset.